# PHP SoapClient syntax

Tags: php

I'm trying to migrate a legacy PHP script to a new server with the latest version of PHP on.

While it works fine on the old server, the new one seems to fail on this line:

```
$client=new SoapClient('http://www.***.co.uk/external/?r=api/service');
```

Has the syntax for SoapClient changed?

Thanks

Comment: Have you opened a manual?

Comment: What's the error message? The syntax didn't change at all. Most probably the new server lacks the [PHP extensions required for SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php) (SOAP, XML etc)

Comment: Thanks, php-soap wasn't installed. All sorted now.